# Como Redirecciono a otra página a través de un botón siguiendo las condiciones en javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

No pongo todo el form porque no me deja pero si me cumplen las condiciones solo no sé como hacer para que me mande a otra página cumpliendo estas .

```
<form>
<button >Aceptar y Continuar</button>
</form>
```

Las condiciones en js con lo que se tiene que cumplir son la siguientes:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');

var usuario = document.getElementById('username');

var email = document.getElementById('email');

var clave = document.getElementById('password');

var clave2 = document.getElementById('password2');
```

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {

```
e.preventDefault();

checkInputs();
```

});

function MostrarError(input, mensaje) {

```
var formControl = input.parentElement;

var small = formControl.querySelector('small');

formControl.className = 'form-control error';

small.innerText = mensaje;
```

}

function MostrarAcierto(input) {

```
var formControl = input.parentElement;

formControl.className = 'form-control success';
```

}

function Correo(email) {

```
return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
```

}
function checkInputs() {

```
var UsuarioValor = usuario.value.trim();

var CorreoValor = email.value.trim();

var ContraseñaValor = clave.value.trim();

var Contraseña2Valor = clave2.value.trim();

if(UsuarioValor === '') {
    MostrarError(usuario, 'No puede dejar el usuario en blanco')
} else {
    MostrarAcierto(usuario)
}

if(CorreoValor === '') {
    MostrarError(email, 'No puede dejar el Email en blanco');
} else if (!Correo(CorreoValor)) {
    MostrarError(email, 'No ingreso un Email Válido');
} else {
    MostrarAcierto(email)
}

if(ContraseñaValor === '') {
    MostrarError(clave, 'La Contraseña no puede quedar en Blanco');
} else {
    MostrarAcierto(clave)
}

if(Contraseña2Valor === '') {
    MostrarError(clave2, 'Debe Repetir una Contraseña Válida');
    
} else if(ContraseñaValor !== Contraseña2Valor) {
    MostrarError(clave2, 'Las Contraseñas no Coinciden');
} else{
    MostrarAcierto(clave2)
}
```

}

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR: Edita la pregunta y coloca código en lugar de imágenes, hay muchos motivos para ello, uno es que incrementas la chance de obtener buenas respuestas porque facilitas el copy/paste, otro motivo es que los enlaces de imágenes pueden expirar y adiós información sustancial de la pregunta. Esas recomendaciones están basadas en años de interacción en este sitio, espero te sean de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: Ya que vas a editar la pregunta y reemplazar las imágenes por texto del código, por favor tómate el tiempo para explicar EN el cuerpo de la pregunta, qué es lo que quieres, qué quieres decir con "ya teniendo js" y demás. Haz de cuenta que no sabemos qué quieres :)

Comment: Ya veo muchas gracias , volveré a formular la pregunta en ese caso

Comment: La puedes [edit], no abras una nueva

Comment: Nunca coloques solo código en la pregunta. En su lugar, describe el escenario de tu problema. El título anterior es parte del cuerpo de la pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.